# Python turtle module .ontimer loop question

Tags: python, loops, turtle-graphics

```
def h1():
    tess.forward(70)
    tess.fillcolor("orange")
def h2():
    tess.forward(70)
    tess.fillcolor("red")

def h3():
    tess.back(140)
    tess.fillcolor("green")

timer = 1000

for _ in range(timer):
    wn.ontimer(h1,timer)
    wn.ontimer(h2, timer+1000)
    wn.ontimer(h3, timer+2000)
    timer +=3000

wn.listen()
wn.mainloop()
```

When I use the for loop the function works as intended.
when I try to use the while loop, nothing happens, no runtime error either:

```
while True:
    wn.ontimer(h1,timer)
    wn.ontimer(h2, timer+1000)
    wn.ontimer(h3, timer+2000)
    timer +=3000
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say both your `for` loop and `while` loop are questionable in the manner they launch timers, I would have expected more of a handoff like:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

TIME = 1000  # in milliseconds

def h1():
    tess.forward(70)
    tess.fillcolor("orange")
    screen.ontimer(h2, TIME)

def h2():
    tess.forward(70)
    tess.fillcolor("red")
    screen.ontimer(h3, TIME)

def h3():
    tess.back(140)
    tess.fillcolor("green")
    screen.ontimer(h1, TIME)

screen = Screen()

tess = Turtle()

h1()

screen.mainloop()
```

But there's not sufficient code in your question to understand the big picture.